# In light of Romans 5:13, why was pre-flood humanity destroyed before the giving of the Law?

Tags: genesis, romans, law

According to Romans 5:13, pre-flood humanity was not judged guilty of sin according to the Law [of Moses] because,

> <sup>13</sup> for sin indeed was in the world before the law was given, but sin is not counted where there is no law. <sup>ESV, ©2016</sup>

Note: “before the law was given” and “sin is not counted where there is no law”

Logically, if sin is not counted where there is no law, and the law had not yet been given before the flood, those people should not have been judged and destroyed
by God with the flood. So, what is the legal basis (so to speak) for God’s judgment of humanity before the Law was given?

Comment: This question is all over the place. What is the specific text being asked about? What is the specific question? I've edited the question to help myself (and others) by making it clearer what is part of your question vs. textual quotes but this more clearly shows the underlying confusion about what text you're actually asking about.

Comment: @Dan  I think this is an excellent and well thought out question and move to reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

The context indicates that the people are still judged -- thus, *some* transgression must still be "charged" or "accounted" to them.  Look and the verse after it:

Yet death reigned from Adam to Moses [since death happened, there must be sin and transgression], even over those whose sinning was not like the transgression of Adam [Adam sinned against a specific commandment; those alive between Adam and the giving of the Law did not have specific, codified commandments], who was a type of the one who was to come.

Rom 2:15 indicates that the "work of the Law" is written on the hearts of those without it.  In other words, the law still applies even if you don't know about it.  I forget the legal term for this, but it exists.  Like if you don't know the speed limit, the officer can still give you a ticket.  Ignorance doesn't make you "less" guilty -- but knowledge does make you "more" guilty.  Also, 2:12-14 shows that those without the Law (which people from Adam to Moses would be) are a "law unto themselves, even though they do not have the law."  People in general ARE under "law" (Christians would call this the moral law of God), even if not "The" Mosaic Law.  So, yes, Rom 5 is saying those people were not judged according to the Mosaic Law.